# how to view file saved via content Content Resolver

Tags: java, android

I have saved a PDF file to the documents directory using contentResolver. it is getting saved successfully. However, I'm not able to open the file via code.

following is the code

```
public void saveToExternalStorage(File file, Context context) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "order" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf");
        cv.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
        cv.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents");
        cv.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), cv);
        if (uri != null) {

            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                fis.read(bytes);
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.close();
                Log.e("file", "saved" + uri);
                cv.put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 0);
                resolver.update(uri, cv, null, null);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", Log.getStackTraceString(e.fillInStackTrace()));
            }
        }
    }
```

the emulator opens an app with a blank screen.
[image]

Comment: `saved a PDF file to the documents directory using contentResolver.` That content resolver is irrelevant. What you did:  `saved a PDF file to the Documents directory using the MediaStore.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to add is a READ permission flag to the intent.